# High performance WSGI application

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgi

We would like to develop high performance WSGI application in python. This application should serve html or JSON both depening on requirement.There will not be any backend database.

As per my understanding Django not suits well to my requirements. It seems me using Django is overburden because we don't need many of its features. What we basically need is router+controller+view.

Also performance is our big concern. I am going though different banchmarkings and found that Djnago is really slow. 
https://falconframework.org/

Keeping all this in view it seems me that we should write our own framework by using some fastest router libraries but this will still be reinventing the wheels.

Please note I have developed database centric web application in Django and it worth to use Django there. But when there is no database and performance really matters then based on different banchmark and own experience it not seems good choice.

Is there any other better minimal web framework that we can use? 
Or if suggestion is to write new one then it will be great if you provide few examples.

Below are few links:
https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/do-it-yourself.html
http://funwithlinux.net/2015/11/how-to-write-a-python-web-framework-from-scratch/

Any expert guidance is really helpful!
Thanks in advance

Comment: GIve a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Comment: If you are chasing performance without having written a line of code, why are you looking at just WSGI. And why Python 2.7. Look at Python 3 and aiohttp instead. https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/